# Extending ActiveRecord in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've followed this guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#add-an-acts-as-method-to-active-record

In fact, I've actually copied the code and put into my app and it doesn't work.

I keep getting undefined method errors.

When I use console, I can check if the module is initialized and it is, but the model that uses the "acts_as" method throws undefined method errors.

Also in console I can call `ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ...` explicitly and then it includes the module -- then everything works. But try as I may, I can't get rails to call `.send` on ActiveRecord::Base at load time.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you including the module in your model code. Post the model code and it will be easier to help.

Comment: The same as I do for any other "acts_as" type module. It's just a class method. I've done this before many times with rails, just not in rails 4.2.